# Como eu uso repetições aninhadas para fazer este exemplo?

Tags: javascript, portugol

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Como faço isso com repetições aninhadas usando o `for` do JavaScript, ou no VisuAlg?

para voces terem uma ideia de como seria o codigo :

```
    for(var linha = 0; linha < 10; linha = linha++) {
         for(var coluna = 0; coluna < 10; coluna = coluna++) {          Document.write("*"); 
}
 Document. Write("");
 }
```

Ta assim, mas não consigo pensar em nada para dar aquele efeito usando dois loop

Comment: Não precisa aninhar laços pra imprimir isso na tela.

Comment: Queres fazer isso onde? numa página de html?

Comment: É aninhar, já editei.

Comment: Qual é a necessidade do segundo `for`? É porque irás usar caracteres diferentes? Queremos ajudar mas acho que ainda não está claro o que falta nas respostas já dadas.

Comment: É uma lição. E ela esta pedindo para fazer esse exercicio com 2 for

Comment: Ah!... ok, então podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/ykmq1rnt/ Era isso que procuravas?

Comment: Não entendi esse link

Comment: @H.VCeaser Se alguma das respostas te ajudou a resolver o problema, marque-a como aceita clicando na "seta" abaixo da pontuação!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se quiseres fazer esse efeito com JavaScript podes fazer assim:

```js
var string = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var stars = Array.apply(null, Array(i)).map(function(){return '*'});
    string.push(stars.join(''));
}
document.body.innerHTML = string.join('<br>');
```

Isso cria 20 linhas dentro de uma array e depois podes juntar numa string para HTML com `<br>` entre cada linha para a quebra de linha.

Uma versão com JavaScript mais moderno poderia ser:

```js
const string = [...Array(20)].map(
    (u, i) => [...Array(i)].map(() => '*').join('')
);
document.body.innerHTML = string.join('<br>');
```

Ou usando o novo método [`.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) como indicado [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152438/129):

```js
const string = [...Array(20)].map((u, i) => '*'.repeat(i));
document.body.innerHTML = string.join('<br>');
```

---

#### Nota:

depois de ler o [comentário que escreveste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152436/como-eu-uso-repeti%C3%A7%C3%B5es-aninhadas-para-fazer-este-exemplo#comment314684_152436), deixo uma versão também com 2 loops for, caso prefiras usar esta:

```js
var linhas = 20;
var texto = []
for (var i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
 var string = '';
 for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
  string += '*';
 }
 texto.push(string);
}
document.body.innerHTML = texto.join('<br>');
```

Comment: Sim, mas preciso ultilizar 2 estrutura de repetição aninhadas.

Comment: @H.VCeaser como assim 2? lado a lado? o que o meu código gera seria qual parte?

Comment: Sergio, acho que ele quer dizer que precisa utilizar um for dentro de outro, onde um controla o numero de estrelas na linha, e o outro controla apenas a mudança de linha

Comment: @H.VCeaser podes dar um exemplo estático do resultado que pretendes? é como o diegofm sugeriu? que queres ter 2 loops simultâneos?

Answer (score 10):

Você pode usar o [`String.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) para repetir uma sequência de acordo com a iteração atual do *loop*:

```js
for (var contagem = 1; contagem < 11; contagem++) {
    console.log("*".repeat(contagem));
}
```

Para fazer o mesmo em dois *loops* aninhados, faça assim:

```js
var linhas = 11;

for (var linha = 1; linha < linhas; linha++) { // 1 até 11
   for (var coluna = linha; ; coluna++) {      // De 1 até 11, porém sem condição
       console.log("*".repeat(coluna));
       break; // Interrompe o segundo loop
   } 
}
```

O primeiro [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) vai repetir o código até que a iteração atual alcance o valor de `linhas`. O segundo `for` irá apenas acompanhar o primeiro pois não foi especificado uma condição para repetir o seu código.

Comment: Quase isso, tenho que usar 2 estrutura de repetição. Uma dentro da outra. ( coluna e linha )

Comment: Boa! `+1` pelo `.repeat()`

Comment: @H.VCeaser Veja se é isso. Valeu Sergio o teu ficou ótimo também!

Comment: Estava a rever a tua resposta agora com o duplo `for`. Neste caso o segundo `for` nem chega a correr uma vez. Acho que só complica, seria melhor como tens na primeira versão.

Comment: @Sergio De fato! ele corre junto com o primeiro, concordo que a primeira versão é mais adequada, mas o OP quer usar dois `for`, essa foi a forma que encontrei para fazer isso. :)